# What process would I use to bring a user field from a project template to a project

Tags: acumatica

I have a customization that adds a user field to PMTask so that it shows up in both the Project Templates screen and the Project screen.

What I'd like to be able to do is, when the template is selected in the Projects screen for a new project, bring over that PMTask user field's value (saved in the template) to the new project's PMTask grid.  Right now, it only brings over the standard fields.

Is there a method I can override or re-write to add that functionality?  I've looked in the source  code, but the PMProject.templateID's FieldUpdated event is marked [Obsolete] and has no code.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks...

Comment: You can implement your FieldUpdated event in your extension, that won't be obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the ProjectEntry.cs graph in the extension library, you can find the function that executes the code for updating from a template

```
public virtual void DefaultFromTemplate(PMProject prj, int? templateID, DefaultFromTemplateSettings settings)
```

Copying the tasks is executed from a private function, which we cannot override:(

```
    private PMTask CopyTask(PMTask task, int ProjectID)
```

So to get around this, you could find a field updated event that is being triggered, such as the task's templateID, and then copy the fields over. Here would be such a function:

```
        protected virtual void _(Events.FieldUpdated<PMTask.templateID> e, PXFieldUpdated del)
        {
            //call delegate first
            del?.Invoke(e.Cache, e.Args);
            int? TemplateID = (int?)e.NewValue;
            if (TemplateID != null)
            {
                //get template
                PMTask template = PMTask.PK.Find(Base, TemplateID);
                if (template != null)
                {
                    //get dac extension
                    PMTaskExtension templateExt = template.GetExtension<PMTaskExtension>();
                    //set current custom field from the template's custom field.
                    e.Cache.SetValueExt<PMTaskExtension.customField>(e.Row, templateExt.customField);
                }
            }
        }
```

Now, if the event handler is not being triggered, it could be how they are updating. You would then need to trap the RowUpdating event on the PMTask row, and then check to see if TemplateID is being set AND changed, and then do the same code to update.

Another way around it would be to override the DefaultFromTemplate function, then at the end, go back through each of the tasks, and if a template set, go to that task and pull over any information.